# Modifying the content of an ArrayList which is put in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have two ArrayLists of type RemoveTest. And I have put them in a Map.
Further, I have to iterate over the map and for each arraylist i need to check 
if any element's mid is same as any other elements 
rmid then remove both such elements from the list.

I have the below code running..but I just need to confirm my approach.
Though I am not removing directly from hashmap.. but from the arraylist 
after the iteration for that arraylist completes. As per my understanding 
ConcurrentModificationException should not come..and approach seems correct 
only
But Can someone please confirm that are there any chances or scenarios where
ConcurrentModificationException can come for my code 
as I am ultimately getting the list contatined in HashMap being modified.

```
    List<RemoveTest> eleList = new ArrayList<RemoveTest>();
    List<RemoveTest> eleList2 = new ArrayList<RemoveTest>();

    Map<String, List<RemoveTest>> testMap =new HashMap<String,List<RemoveTest();
    RemoveTest obj1 = new RemoveTest();
    obj1.setmId("m1");
    obj1.setRmId("");

    RemoveTest obj2 = new RemoveTest();
    obj2.setmId("m2");
    obj2.setRmId("m1");

    RemoveTest obj3 = new RemoveTest();
    obj3.setmId("m3");
    obj3.setRmId("");

    RemoveTest obj4 = new RemoveTest();
    obj4.setmId("m4");
    obj4.setRmId("m3");

    RemoveTest obj5 = new RemoveTest();
    obj5.setmId("m5");
    obj5.setRmId("m4");

    RemoveTest obj = new RemoveTest();
    obj.setmId("m");
    obj.setRmId("");

    eleList.add(obj1);
    eleList.add(obj2);
    eleList.add(obj3);
    eleList.add(obj4);
    eleList.add(obj5);
    eleList.add(obj);

    //new
    RemoveTest obj6 = new RemoveTest();
    obj6.setmId("m6");
    obj6.setRmId("");

    RemoveTest obj7 = new RemoveTest();
    obj7.setmId("m7");
    obj7.setRmId("m6");

    eleList2.add(obj6);
    eleList2.add(obj7);
    testMap.put("t1", eleList);
    testMap.put("21", eleList2);


            Set<RemoveTest> removals = new HashSet<RemoveTest>();
    Set<String> matchingFwdRevMIds = new HashSet<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<RemoveTest>> removeTestMap : testMap.entrySet()){
    List<RemoveTest> grp = removeTestMap.getValue();
    String key = removeTestMap.getKey();
    for (int i=0;i<grp.size();i++){
        RemoveTest fwdM = grp.get(i); 
        String fwdMId = fwdM.getmId();
        if(matchingFwdRevMIds.contains(fwdMId)){
            System.out.println("continue becoz "+ fwdMId );
            continue;
        }
        for (int j=i+1; j<grp.size();j++){
            RemoveTest nextM = grp.get(j);
            String mId = nextM.getmId();
            String revMId = nextM.getRmId();
            if(revMId!=null){
                if(matchingFwdRevMIds.contains(revMId)){
                    System.out.println("adding "+ mId);
                    matchingFwdRevMIds.add(mId);
                    removals.add(nextM);

                }
                    if(revMId.equals(fwdMId)){
                        matchingFwdRevMIds.add(fwdMId);
                        matchingFwdRevMIds.add(mId);
                        removals.add(fwdM);
                        removals.add(nextM);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    grp.removeAll(removals);
    } 

    for(Map.Entry<String, List<RemoveTest>> removeTestMap : testMap.entrySet()){
        List<RemoveTest> grp = removeTestMap.getValue();
        for(RemoveTest test : grp){
            System.out.println("final mid "+ test.getmId());
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, Actaully I am modifying the list after completing iteration.. by removeAll(removals) where removals is a HashSet. Just for the reason I didnot want to modify arraylist while iterating it...I used HashSet for maintaing the items to be removed from ArrayList

Comment: You may want to whittle your example down to just the relevant parts to make it more readable. No need to add this many RemoveTest entries, and you haven't given us the definition of the RemoveTest class. There's also a syntax error in the line that says "new HashMap".

Comment: I will keep in mind from the next time.. to include only the necessary code..

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Erm, I never said anything about an `Iterator`. Second, if the OP expects me to read their code, they should format it properly. Looking at it again, you're actually correct; but that's really not my problem as I shouldn't have to decipher the formatting.

Comment: @BrianRoach Fair enough, but you can just ignore the question if you can't read it. Rather than vote-down the correct answer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I didn't even *look* at your answer. This was a drive-by comment for me after glancing at the code until people starting commenting.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ok apologies. Mustn't assume

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In all fairness, you're right, I probably shouldn't even comment without due diligence even though the formatting makes it misleading; I'm removing my comments re: the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's perfectly fine to modify an object that is used as a **value** in a `HashMap` while your are iterating over the HashMap. The `ConcurrentModificationException` only comes up if you are adding or removing entries to/from the `HashMap` while you're iterating over it.

As an aside, changing the value like you do is fine. But *never* modify an object that is the **key** of HashMap entry while it is in the HashMap. (To be precise, never modify it in such as way that its hashCode is changed and/or its equals method produces a different result) or else you may not be able to find your entry anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I will continue with this approach.